# How do I solve “pushed branch tip is behind” on subtree when deploying to Heroku with Git?

Tags: git, heroku, git-subtree

I'm trying to push my build folder, dist-new, with this command:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist-new heroku master
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/it
ribe-frontend.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is be
hind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the re
mote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help'
```

I can't force the deployment, because git subtree does not have a force option.

Googling around, I've seen a recommendation to do this:

```
git push heroku git subtree split --prefix dist master:master --force
```

But that throws this error:

```
error: unknown option `prefix'
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting this error because you rebased locally? If local is truly behind remote why not `git fetch —all` then `git rebase origin/master`? Also, does heroku currently reflect origin?

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You likely aren’t using an up to date version of git

## Solution

The prefix option is still available in the latest version of git (see here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh)

`git subtree split -- prefix`

Also you need to execute the command as a sub shell you can’t just do:

`git push heroku git subtree split --prefix dist master:master --force`

You must do:

```
git push heroku $(git subtree split --prefix dist master:master) --force
```

## References

Git Subtree source code: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh

Comment: Nope.

```
git
push heroku $(git subtree split --prefix dist master:master)
--force
error: unknown option `prefix'
usage: git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

That's on the terminal in Webstorm immediately after installing the latest version of Git for Windows.

Comment: @BorisK what version of git?

Comment: Version 2.28, the latest.

Comment: @BorisK is this the version returned in CLI or GUI? Very strange if CLI. Also, `git subtree` should return “usage” do you see the prefix option when you do that?

Comment: git subtree does return the prefix option. 

git version returns git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Comment: @BorisK interesting. Instead of —prefix can you try -P and let me know what that returns for you

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

https://coderwall.com/p/okrlzg/take-control-of-your-heroku-git-repository

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-repo.git
$ heroku repo:reset -a appname
```